# would making the Police a branch of the Military meet the demand of abolishing the police?

Tags: military, police

during a conversation with my family yesterday, an idea came to me of merging the Police and military as a potential solution to the demand of abolishing the police, but at the same time retaining a law enforcement presence in the USA.

How viable an idea is this?

Comment: You do realise that one of the major complaints against the police is the increasing militarisation of the American police force?

Comment: You mean the [Military Police](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Police_Corps_(United_States))?

Comment: Is negative viability a thing?

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same old police, just under a new name?  Problem is not the existence of the police, but their attitudes & behavior.

Comment: If you rename the police to the quagga office does that meet the requirement of abolishing the police?

Comment: I think the answer to this question will both be very broad and depend heavily on what you mean by "merge the police and the military".  Could you expand on that a bit?

Comment: I'm surprised that this question got closed as 'opinion-based.' What it proposes is a very bad idea, but it can be answered with a history of more and less successful police reform processes.

Answer (score 3):

**Difficult.**

To put it as neutral as possible, some people in the United States believe that racism and abuse of power go way beyond "a few bad apples" and that "the police" is incapable of being reformed. There have been international examples where the military has replaced the police because the police was deemed unsuitable and incapable of reform.

- Brazil uses [military police](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batalh%C3%A3o_de_Opera%C3%A7%C3%B5es_Policiais_Especiais) for peacetime law enforcement. There have been complaints about human rights violations.
- So does Mexico. Again there are [complaints](https://www.hrw.org/news/2018/10/05/mexico-militarization-public-security) about human rights violations.

I'm sure there were some examples where it worked out, but I can't think of any right now.

***If* there is a problem, it is the culture and not the logo on the uniforms.**

Some people disagree that there is a systematic problem. Assuming for the sake of argument that such a problem exists, merging the existing police forces with the military won't resolve it. Dismissing all police and employing the existing infantry for law enforcement might make a difference, but not necessarily for the better -- see the examples above.